# Установка Tomcat на выделенном сервере

Tags: java, сервер, jsp, tomcat, scp

Доброго времени суток!

Рабочая web-система писалась и запускалась на локальном сервере (домашнем компьютере). Теперь, необходимо загрузить результаты трудов на выделенный сервер. Доступ к нему осуществляется по SSH/SCP через VPN-соединение. При подключении к серверу вижу такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: куда загрузить Tomcat и как его запустить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030725/java-install-tomcat-as-service это не оно?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по "простыне", вы заходите из Win на Linux сервер.
Единственное, что не понятно, какой именно Linux у вас стоит на сервере - deb- или rpm-based.
Если deb(Debian, Ubuntu) - хороший мануал от DO - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04

Если rpm-based(CentOS) - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7